# GNU ddrescue "Rescued" is larger than the HDD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ddrescue

I am using ddrescue to recover data from a failing drive. The drive is being read as 596.2 GB via the `lsblk` command.

The thing that is confusing me is that ddrescue is showing that it has, so far, rescued a total of 633000 MB (600+ GB).

I would have to imagine that ddrescue is screwing up and reading invalid data, or that lsblk is reporting an incorrect size of the disk. Could someone clear this up for me?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the command I'm using `ddrescue /dev/sda img.dd log.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lsblk` uses legacy power-of-1024 prefixes (K, M, G, T, etc.). GNU `ddrescue` reports its progress with power-of-1000 SI prefixes by default (k, M, G, T, etc.). 596.2 GiB is just over 640 GB (a common capacity for laptop HDDs). 640 − 633 = about 7 GB not rescued.

`lsblk -b` (or `lsblk --bytes`) will report exact sizes in bytes. Alternatively, `ddrescue` can use powers of 1024 and IEC prefixes with the `-B` (`--binary-prefixes`) option.